# Incorrect integer value: '' for column `x`.`x`.`x` at > row 1

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Tengo una landing de registro donde colocas email y provincia, y los datos se guardan en la tabla REGISTRO.

Todas las provincias están cargadas en otra tabla (que se llama idxProv), entonces seleccionas del dropdown tu provincia y listo.

El problema es al seleccionar la provincia surge el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: idxProv in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sitio_website\creartestdrop.php on line 48 Error:
>   INSERT INTO registro (email, idxProv) VALUES ('a@a.com', '') Incorrect
>   integer value: '' for column `sitio_website`.`registro`.`idxProv` at
>   row 1

*Parece que no identifica las provincias.*

Este es el formulario en .php (No tengo problema en que se muestren y se seleccionen las provincias):

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("sitio", "usuario", "contraseña", "nombre");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  </head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="creartestdrop.php" method="POST">


      <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingrese email" required>
      </div>

<select id="idxProv">
  <option disabled selected>Seleccione provincia</option>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['idxProv'] ?>"><?php echo $row['provincia'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>

 <button type="submit">Finalizar</button>

 </form>
```

Crear registro:

```
<?php

    include 'conn.php';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Query to check if the email already exist
    $checkEmail = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' ";

    // Variable $result hold the connection data and the query
    $result = $conn-> query($checkEmail);

    // Variable $count hold the result of the query
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If count == 1 that means the email is already on the database
    if ($count == 1) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning mt-4' role='alert'>
                    <p>Este email ya se encuentra registrado en la base de datos.</p>

                    </div>";
    } else {    

    /*
    If the email don't exist, the data from the form is sended to the
    database and the account is created
    */
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $idxProv = $_POST['idxProv'];

    // Query to send Email and Provincia hash to the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO registro (email, idxProv) VALUES ('$email', '$idxProv')";



    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-4' role='alert'><p>Ha sido creada.</p>
        <a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='lista.php' role='button'>Finalizar</a></div>";     
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }   
    }   
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola, antes de hacer todos tus movimientos, qué tienes en el momento como valor en la variable $_POST['idxProv']?

Comment: Solo $provincia que tiene todas las provincias

Comment: Puede ser que cuando registra los datos en la base tenga que escribir que se conecte a la otra tabla? Como algo así: 
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){`

Recién lo intente y el error cambio, pero sigue sin solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que $_POST no toma el valor del `select` por su id, sino por su name, por lo que tendrías que cambiarlo por:

```
<select id="idxProv" name="idxProv">
  <option disabled selected>Seleccione provincia</option>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['idxProv'] ?>"><?php echo $row['provincia'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```